# Hello, I am having a problem with the "Random" library in python

Tags: python, random

Hello I am having a problem with the "random" library in python. So basically I want it to return a value between (1, 99) so that part works but I want it to return multiple random values by only running the code once. It only gives me 1 random value for each run. Here is the code:

```
import random
import time
 
Random = random.randint(1, 99)
while True:
    time.sleep(0.7)
    print(Random)
```

And I also wanted to ask that how to time a function in python. If I only want it to run for a specific amount of time, how do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Call `random.randint` in your loop to get a new random number every iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a list of random integers in a single call you can use `choices` or `sample` from the `random` standard library along with `range` to get what you want:

```
import random

# 10 random integers between 1-99 with replacement
print(random.choices(range(1, 100), k=10))

# 10 random integers between 1-99 without replacement
print(random.sample(range(1, 100), k=10))
```

```
[45, 52, 36, 43, 46, 28, 43, 37, 37, 17]
[63, 10, 40, 38, 86, 87, 65, 37, 15, 49]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
import time

while True:
    Random = random.randint(1, 99)
    print(Random)
    time.sleep(0.7)
```

If you want it to run as fast as possible for 0.7 seconds:

```
import random
import time

alarm = time.time() + 0.7
while time.time() < alarm:
    Random = random.randint(1, 99)
    print(Random)
```

Note that this is a tight CPU loop, and thus is not a good idea, but it shows you the concept.

Comment: Thanks so much for all of your answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the random number using the random library was declared only once outside the while.

As you answer above, you can put random number generation into the while loop.

You can also check it using a for-loop.

```
from random import randint

for _ in range(10):
    random_num= randint(0, 10)
    print(random_num)
```

output

```
1
3
4
9
4
2
7
5
1
6
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import random 
n = 20 
random_num_list = random.sample(list(range(1,99)), n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random
for i in range(3):
    print(random.randint(1,99)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    # Imports
    import random
    import time

    # Working
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.7)
        Random = random.randint(1, 99)
        print(Random)
```